# How to add flow arrows to groundwater table map?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, 3d-analyst, flow

After I had created groundwater table map, I tried using 3D Analyst>Steepest Path to add groundwater flow arrows to the map. However, it didn't work.

Would you please let me know how can I add these flow lines to the groundwater table map?